# IIS 7.5 - AngularJS 1.4 Routing improper behavior

Tags: angularjs, html, iis-7.5, angularjs-routing

I have a website, which I am running thru VS 2015, working correctly, however when deploy to IIS 7.5 some improper behavior.

See following details about my site:

**1.** `IIS Application name`: `AngularSchoolSystem`

**2.** Index.html : `<base href=""  />`

**3.** Index.html HyperLinks:

```
<li role="presentation" class="active"> <a href="#Student">Student</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#Teacher">Teacher</a> </li>
```

**3.** Routing Code:

```
.when("/Student", {
    templateUrl: "/views/students/student.html",
    controller: "studentController"
})
.when("/Restaurant", {
        templateUrl: "/views/teachers/teacher.html",
        controller: "restaurantController"
})
```

When I run this thru IIS first time : `http://localhost/AngularSchoolSystem/` it correctly loads home page, however when I click on any of link `Student`, or `Teacher`, browser URL is not considering application name and changing it to `http://localhost/#Student`, and showing IIS level default  image.

Comment: It's because you've structured your app in IIS as a virtual directory.  You should consider changing it to a standalone site with a dedicated dns binding OR consider properly handling root routing in your app code.

Comment: @DavidL, So you are saying there will be always these issues, if I deploy & run application thru IIS locally? This is working fine if I run thru Visual Studio 2015. What is another alternative way to make it run on local, than IIS & Visual Studio?